# radial gradient not displaying correctly in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, gradient, radial

I am having a problem displaying a radial gradient on my website in Firefox. The gradient seems to work fine in Edge and Chrome but not Firefox.

In chrome and edge I get this:

[image: In chrome and edge I get this]

This is what I see in Firefox:

[image: This is what I see in Firefox]

```
body{
  background-color: blue;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #0047ea 0%, #151515 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(#0047ea,#151515 );
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a height on the body. Setting it to `100vh` will make the gradient cover the screen.

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #0047ea 0%, #151515 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(#0047ea, #151515);
  z-index: 0;
  
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: @HenryOliver It looks like you're new to Stack Overflow. Decent first question! Just a reminder, if you haven't seen, you should accept the answer that helps you out.

Comment: I'm trying lol but for some reason I need to wait another minute

Comment: Oh, haha forgot there's a 15 minute wait limit. Just wasn't sure if you were aware of that functionality. It also gives you rep.

Comment: there we go marked as solved! thanks again for your help

Comment: @HenryOliver an easier fix is to simply add `html{height:100%}` ... you may refer to the duplicate question for more details